# I Tried to upload my csv file datasets but weka is not recognizing it

Tags: dataset, weka, kaggle

I tried uploading my datasets on weka but I keep getting "java.io.IOException
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DBypoKEnU9iFO2YNLUKbtkxnO-A2BIWe/view?usp=sharing this is the datasets. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Weka's CSVLoader only works with a small subset of CSV dialects. You can install and use [common-csv-weka-package](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package), which loads your CSV just fine.

Be aware, that you need Weka 3.9.5 or later for this package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have Weka running under Linux (Manjaro) and Windows 10. I could open the csv file of the dataset in Weka running under Manjaro by opening it straight from Preprocess > Open file...
However when I tried doing that in Weka running in Windows 10 I got the Java IOException. I think it was tripping on text with accented characters.

I fixed this by opening the csv file in Notepad++ in Windows 10. The encoding was utf-8. When I changed it to ANSI it then opened fine.